# Using ScriptProcessorNode for playing audio yields a light background noise

Tags: audio, web, web-audio-api

I am working on a projects that needs to connect to an existing video tag grab the audio, and do some small manipulations to the audio.

```html
var MyContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var source = MyContext.createMediaElementSource(video);
audioScript = MyContext.createScriptProcessor(512,2,2);
source.connect(audioScript);
audioScript.connect(MyContext.destination);

audioScript.onaudioprocess = function(audioProcessingEvent) {
     var inputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.inputBuffer;

  // The output buffer contains the samples that will be modified and played
  var outputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.outputBuffer;
  for (var channel = 0; channel < 2; channel++) 
  {
   var inputData = inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
   outputBuffer.copyToChannel(inputData, channel);
  }

    }
```

The issue is that I keep getting a light background noise on the audio. Even if I do nothing just copy the input to the output I hear that light noise.

Any Idea what is the reason for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a higher buffer size, it may well be slightly dropping frames once it is actually being rendered. Not all devices play the same and I find Chrome especially does not play nice with ScriptProcessorNodes below 1024 samples regardless of what they are actually doing.